Is there a framework of many open-source code LLMs for generation?
While there seem to be many frameworks out there to run evaluation on code LLMs (for benchmarking purposes), I cannot seem to find a project/framework that like lists 10 (or more, some papers have 50+) popular LLMs (specifically focused at code generation), and has an easy function to call with a prompt, which then returns like a .json with all the responses of each model.
Could anyone point me to such a resource if it does exist? Preferably in Python. Many thanks!
So far I have found https://github.com/bigcode-project/bigcode-evaluation-harness and EvalPlus, yet they focus mainly on evaluation and still require you to configure all the models etc. I would like something that has that part set up, like a plug-and-play code generation tool for benchmarking.

Does this help? https://huggingface.co/models?pipeline_tag=text-generation&sort=trending&search=code

@SilentCloud thank you, this does help with the list of models I can use for code generation. However, they all output different formats, e.g. some still reply with a generic answer first (along the lines of "Sure! The final code would be:") or some continue the write beyond the function that needs to be completed. Hence, an overarching framework that pre- and post-processes the input and output for these models is what I am mainly searching for, as now it requires quite some manual labour instead of running an automated generation (+ evaluation) framework for benchmarks. Thanks for the reply!
